# sudo apt update fails with "E: Method http has died unexpectedly! E: Sub-process http received signal 7"

Tags: apt, package-management, 22.04

I recently upgraded to Ubuntu 22.04 and ran `sudo apt update` and `upgrade` and both were successful. After a reboot, when I tried to run apt update, I got the following error:

```
Reading package lists... Done
E: Method http has died unexpectedly!
E: Sub-process http received signal 7.
E: Method /usr/lib/apt/methods/http did not start correctly
E: Method http has died unexpectedly!
E: Sub-process http received signal 7.
E: Method /usr/lib/apt/methods/http did not start correctly
E: Method http has died unexpectedly!
E: Sub-process http received signal 7.
E: Method /usr/lib/apt/methods/http did not start correctly
E: Method http has died unexpectedly!
E: Sub-process http received signal 7.
E: Method /usr/lib/apt/methods/http did not start correctly
E: Method https has died unexpectedly!
E: Sub-process https received signal 7.
E: Method /usr/lib/apt/methods/https did not start correctly
E: Failed to fetch http://in.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/jammy/InRelease  
E: Failed to fetch http://in.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/jammy-updates/InRelease  
E: Failed to fetch http://in.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/jammy-backports/InRelease  
E: Failed to fetch http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/jammy-security/InRelease  
E: Failed to fetch https://dl.google.com/linux/chrome/deb/dists/stable/InRelease  
E: Some index files failed to download. They have been ignored, or old ones used instead.
```

I looked at other Q&As, but they're not exactly the same. E.g. I could find answers for `Sub-process http received signal 4` but for my error case `Sub-process http received signal 7`.

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Do you have `apt-transport-https` installed?

Comment: @popey. Yes. But I am closing this question as it's not relevant. In my case, my disk was corrupted sou machine was behaving unexpectedly.